# In SAS Enterprise Miner, how can I tell the categories to which dummy variables correspond?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS EM, and I'm having difficulty interpreting the results of a linear regression model.

I have a categorical variable (state) that's been converted to binary dummy variables, but how can I tell which one corresponds to which state? For example, is `G_State 0` Hawaii or California?

[image: SAS EM regression output]

Comment: How to interpret output can be on topic here, but I don't see how this can be answered from what you have here.

Comment: @gung Presumably the answer is just whatever method SAS uses to order the levels of a categorical variable. Somebody who knows SAS better than me could probably tell us that.

Comment: @gung If you can let me know what more information you need, then I'd be happy to provide it. I agree with Kodiologist that someone who knows SAS should be able to answer this, because it's an automated process out of the box. I used a default variable selector node, 60/40 partition, and plugged it into a stepwise linear regression node. I've explored the variables in each node, but don't see any maps. It's difficult to guess which were removed because the numbering is restarted in the final output (so I couldn't even assume an alphabetical sort).

Comment: Wow, that isn't great software design if it shuffles your categories & doesn't tell you which is which. I suspect I could figure it out if i were there, but I don't know what to tell you from here. In general, SAS takes the last category as your reference category & I might suspect the others are ordered as originally, but who knows? On a different note, stepwise selection is generally not recommended (& especially not interpreting those p-values afterwards), but I don't know what it's doing w/ the holdout dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great answer, but you could check the n's or some other stat that differs between the levels of the variable recorded as a a dummy variable. For example, if you have 20 cases for California, the dummy variable with an n of 20 is California. But, I am sure there is some way to see this more easily. EM is so useful and makes my work so fast in so many ways, but there are these little issues with the design that make no sense.

Still, EM makes everything faster overall, so I put up with it. I ran into the same issue, so will update if I find a better solution.

Comment: Awesome, do let me know if you figure it out, but that helps.